# How to click on a pop-up button with Selenium using Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I want to click on a popup window but after trying several ways, I obtain a "TimeoutException" error.

This is the code that I'm trying:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='modal-footer modal-footer-gallit-postula' and @id='modal_comentarios']"))).click()
```

And I attach an image of the html[image]

For further information, the popup is very similar to the one appearing in the url below after clicking on the green button that says "Postular" (to get the exact popup it's necessary to be logged in). https://trabajo.gallito.com.uy/anuncio/vendedor-automotriz-qm995

Answer (score 1):

The desired element is within a [Modal Dialog Box](https://www.w3schools.com/Bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp) so to click on the ***clickable*** element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.modal-footer.modal-footer-gallit-postula > button.btn.btn-primary.btn-color-postula"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='btn btn-primary btn-color-postula' and text()='Aceptar']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use time.sleep() to handle this. For context:

```
    from selenium import...
    import time

    driver.get(url)
    butn = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='//* 
    [@id="postular"]').click() 
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='____').click()
```

-I don't have the credentials to login, but this is how i handle modal alerts