Getting coordinates from openlayers map
I have an openlayers map with a vehicle route and it's speed at certain points. To get the speed I need to click on a pin button on the map that opens a pop-up with some info (speed, time, geolocation, etc). What I'm trying to do is to get these data to populate a spreadsheet. This is part of a larger scraping I'm doing with Selenium in the same environment. The problem: I can't for the life of me figure out how to automate the clicks on the pins, since there's only one element for the pop-up that changes it's info with each new click. Maybe there's a way to extract the data without the need to click on the pins, but I have no idea if that's possible.
Here's the snippet with the popup content that I want:
<div class="ol-overlay-container ol-selectable" style="position: absolute; left:537px; top: 281px;">
<div id="popup" class="ol-popup">
<a href="#" id="popup-closer" class="ol-popup-closer">
</a><div id="popup-content">Hora: 16:11:59<br><br>Velocidade: 65.75 km/h<br><br>Lat: -12.9552641<br><br>Lon: -38.4291202<br><br>Precisão: 3.9m</div></div></div>

Edit:
The map as it appears on the html source:
<div id="map" class="map">
                        <div class="ol-viewport" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; width: 100%; height: 100%;"><div class="ol-unselectable ol-layers" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 0;"><div class="ol-layer" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%;"><canvas width="782" height="600" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; transform-origin: left top; transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);"></canvas></div></div><div class="ol-overlaycontainer" style="position: absolute; z-index: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div><div class="ol-overlaycontainer-stopevent" style="position: absolute; z-index: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;"><div class="ol-overlay-container ol-selectable" style="position: absolute; display: none;"><div id="popup" class="ol-popup">
                          <a href="#" id="popup-closer" class="ol-popup-closer"></a>
                          <div id="popup-content"></div>
                        </div></div><div class="ol-zoom ol-unselectable ol-control"><button class="ol-zoom-in" type="button" title="Zoom in">+</button><button class="ol-zoom-out" type="button" title="Zoom out">−</button></div><div class="ol-rotate ol-unselectable ol-control ol-hidden"><button class="ol-rotate-reset" type="button" title="Reset rotation"><span class="ol-compass" style="transform: rotate(0rad);">⇧</span></button></div><div class="ol-attribution ol-unselectable ol-control" style=""><ul><li>© 2024 Microsoft Corporation</li><li>© 2024 TomTom</li><li><a class="ol-attribution-bing-tos" href="https://www.microsoft.com/maps/product/terms.html" target="_blank">Terms of Use</a></li></ul><button type="button" title="Attributions"><span>»</span></button></div></div></div></div>


Have you tried parsing the html snippet and grabbing the div by id? In Python you'd probably use BeautifulSoup4

Here's an example for parsing the html snippet, rather than relying on Selenium to click on the pin.
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
snippet = """<div class="ol-overlay-container ol-selectable" style="position: absolute; left:537px; top: 281px;"><div id="popup" class="ol-popup"><a href="#" id="popup-closer" class="ol-popup-closer"></a><div id="popup-content">Hora: 16:11:59<br><br>Velocidade: 65.75 km/h<br><br>Lat: -12.9552641<br><br>Lon: -38.4291202<br><br>Precisão: 3.9m</div></div></div>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(snippet)
popup = soup.find("div", {"id": "popup-content"})
popup.text
>>> 'Hora: 16:11:59Velocidade: 65.75 km/hLat: -12.9552641Lon: -38.4291202Precisão: 3.9m'


This gives me the data on that specific pin, right?. The popup-content doesn't update if you don't choose a pin in another position.

I sort of assumed that if you look through the source html, you can find the popup data for all the pins. Do you have an example of one of the maps?

It's just a Bing map, I'll edit the original question to add the html source on it

So you're looking for ways to select your the pins?  What are you currently trying? Have a look at e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73534396/how-to-click-on-a-pop-up-button-with-selenium-using-python

Honestly, I have nothing. I have no idea how to figure out where the pins will be, since they're never in the same position. If I had a reliable way to get the coordinates I'd be able to send the mouse over and click them
